# How would I make a VSCode syntax highlighter that is not extremely hard to understand?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to make a custom syntax highlighter for my own markup language. All the examples are complicated, missing steps and are very, very hard to understand.

Is there anything that fully documents how to make a syntax highlighter?

(for VSCode, by the way)

---

For example, this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5msZv-nKebI which has an extremely large skip in the middle and doesn't really explain much.

My current code, made with Yeoman generator is:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinring/tmlanguage/master/tmlanguage.json",
    "name": "BetterMarkupLanguage",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "include": "#keywords"
        },
        {
            "include": "#strings"
        }
    ],
    "repository": {
        "keywords": {
            "patterns": [{
                "name": "entity.other.bml",
                "match": "\\b({|}|\\\\|//)\\b"
            }]
        },
        "strings": {
            "name": "string.quoted.double.bml",
            "begin": "`",
            "end": "`"
        }
    },
    "scopeName": "source.bml"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Synopsis

VS Code uses a `tmLanguage` engine, which means you can write a syntax highlighter at one of two complexities:

- Just identify little nuggets of canonically identifiable tokens (strings, numbers, comments, reserved words, maybe operators) and highlight those, or
- Do the former, and *also* add in context awareness.

If you only want to do the former, that's still better than nothing at all, but I'm going to cover both types in this answer. The two levels of complexity correspond directly to the two basic jobs for a `tmLanguage` engine. These are:

- Assign scopes to text.
- Maintain a stack of contexts.

After scopes have been assigned by your syntax highlighter, the user's [Color Theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes) maps them to colors and styles to apply to the text. (Using established conventions for your scopes helps preserve consistency for colors and styles across multiple languages that a user may have installed.)

## Practical samples

### Assigning a scope

Lets say you make a definition for integers with this snippet:

```json
"integers": {
    "patterns": [{
        "name": "constant.numeric.integer.bml",
        "match": "[+-]\\d+"
    }]
},
```

When the engine encounters text matching the regex pattern in `"match"`, it will select it, assign the scope from `"name"`, and then continue looking for text that matches any regex in the combined list of patterns for the context at the tip of the stack.

### Changing the context stack

Compare the integer definition to your "strings" one:

```json
"strings": {
    "name": "string.quoted.double.bml", // should be string.quoted.backtick.bml
    "begin": "`",
    "end": "`"
},
```

Those `"begin"` and `"end"` markers denote a change in the `tmLanguage` stack. You have pushed into a new context *inside of a string.* Right now, there are no patterns configured to match within this context, but you could do that by adding a `"patterns"` key.

Think about *escaped* backticks: You want to scope those as `constant.character.escape.bml` and stay in the same context within "strings". You don't want an escaped backtick to leave the string context prematurely. Here's an example that assumes double-backticks are escaped:

```json
"strings": {
    "name": "string.quoted.backtick.bml",  // fixed the scope this time
    "begin": "`",
    "end": "`",
    "patterns": [{
        "name": "constant.character.escape.bml",
        "match": "``"
    }]
},
```

Obviously, if your language uses `\` to escape characters, modify the `match` correspondingly. (And don't forget that the JSON needs to escape the `\`s, too!)

### Order of operations

You'll eventually notice that the first pattern encountered is matched. Remember the integers set? What happens when you have `45.125`? It will decide to match the `45` and the `125` *as integers* and ignore the `.` entirely. If you have a "floats" pattern, you want to include that *before* your naïve integer pattern.

```json
"numbers": {
    "patterns": [{
            "name": "constant.numeric.float.bml",
            "match": "[+-]\\d+\\.\\d*"
        }, {
            "name": "constant.numeric.integer.bml",
            "match": "[+-]\\d+"
    }]
},
```

### Reusing patterns

There's another way to write the "numbers" snippet above. A pattern can include other other lists of patterns, even interspersed with its own matches to preserve the order of regex comparison.

This allows you to name and re-use floats and integers in other parts of your highlighter. Notice that the `"include"` for floats comes first, so they will match first inside "numbers" even though they are defined after "integers" in the file.

```json
"numbers": {
    "patterns": [
        {"include": "#floats"},
        {"include": "#integers"}
    ]
},
"integers": {
    "patterns": [{
        "name": "constant.numeric.integer.bml",
        "match": "[+-]\\d+"
    }]
},
"floats": {
    "patterns": [{
        "name": "constant.numeric.float.bml",
        "match": "[+-]\\d+\\.\\d*"
    }]
},
```

## Doing things the right way

The numbers/integers/floats example was trivial, but **well-designed syntax definitions will define utility groups that `"include"` equivalent things together for re-usability:**

- A normal programming language will have things like

  - A **statements** group of all things that can be directly executed. This then may or may not (language-dependent) include...
  - An **expressions** group of things you can put on the right-hand-side of an assignment, which will definitely include...
  - An **atoms** group of strings, numbers, chars, etc. that might also be valid statements, but that also depends on your language.
  - **function-definitions** probably won't be in **expressions** (unless they are lambdas) but probably *would* be in **statements**. Function definitions might push into a context that lets you `return` and so on.
- A markup language like yours might have

  - An **inline** group to keep track of all the markup one can have *within* a block.
  - A **block** group to hold lists, quotes, paragraphs, headers.
  - ...

Though there is more you could learn (capture groups, injections, scope conventions, etc.), this is hopefully a practical overview for getting started.

## Conclusion

When you write your syntax highlighting, think to yourself: Does matching this token put me in a place where things like it can be matched again? Or does it put me in a different place where different things (more *or fewer*) ought to be matched? If the latter, what returns me to the original set of matches?